# TagHelper for ASPNET CORE ViewComponent not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm in the process of getting to grips with ASPNET CORE [version 1.1, using VS2017 Community, version 15.1 (26403.3)]I've created a working ViewComponent called `UserDetails` (abbreviated below):

```
namespace AdminConsole.ViewComponents
{
[ViewComponent(Name = "UserDetails")]
public class UserDetailsViewComponent : ViewComponent
{ ...does stuff... }
```

and I can invoke it successfully in a view by using

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("UserDetails")
```

I'd rather invoke it by using a TagHelper, but it just ain't happening. I've trawled through SO and other helpful pages, and whilst others seem to get it to work, I can't.

I've added the line `@addTagHelper "*, AdminConsole"` in _ViewImports.cshtml and `<vc:user-details></vc:user-details>` in the view I want to render the VC in, and it does not render; I don't get an error, it just doesn't render.

If I change the TagHelper declaration to `@addTagHelper *, AdminConsole` (without the speech marks) it also does not render or error.

If I try both combinations as above and try `<vc:UserDetails></vc:UserDetails>` i.e. without the kebab-case, it does not render or error.

My `_ViewImports.cshtml` is as follows

```
@using AdminConsole
@using AdminConsole.Models
@using AdminConsole.Models.AccountViewModels
@using AdminConsole.Models.ManageViewModels
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration TelemetryConfiguration
@addTagHelper "*, AdminConsole"
```

Using the full namespace for the VC in the `@addTagHelper` declaration (`AdminConsole.ViewComponents`) produces a `cannot resolve TagHelper` error.

I think I've tried all permutations, and documentation from official and community sources only suggest what I've tried (and differ!). I would be very grateful if someone could help shed some light.

Comment: I'm also having this kind of problem, any solutions available?

Comment: Hi Riza, I asked the same questionover on the ASP.NET forums... and sadly no answer. Can you get the VC to render using `@await Component.InvokeAsync("ComponentName")` method? That works for me, but TagHelper is not working.

Comment: yes, @await Component works, but TagHelper doesn't. I'm still trying to find the solution, will post an answer if I ever found one

Comment: is there any dotnet frameworks update? unfortunately I'm using VSCode

Comment: I am also having this issue, and cannot for the life of me figure out why it's not working. I've even built a sample of the code from the Microsoft documentation, and it still only works if I use the razor syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Installing [.NET Core 1.1.2 runtime (Current LTS)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/runtime) solve my problem. I guess we should install both the SDK and the LTS runtime.